# Setting variables using timer in JS

Tags: javascript

trying to figure out how to do this and I'm not too sure. I'm trying to update local GPS coordinates every 3 seconds using `setTimeout` and it's not working properly. I'm very new to js so any help is appreciated.  This is what I have so far-

In my main JS file, I have this...

```
var lat_in={};
var long_in={};
var alt_in={};

$.getScript("test_points.js", function(){
    console.log("TP script go");
});

$("#Initiate").click(function() {

  if (coordinate=="GPS")
     {
     console.log("GPS go");
     lat_out = lat_in;
     long_out = long_in;
     alt_out = alt_in;
         console.log(lat_out, long_out, alt_out)
     }

)}
```

I'm calling the lat/long/alt from another js document (test_points.js), where the `setTimeout` is...

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var lat_in=5;
    var long_in=5;
    var alt_in=-5;
}, 3000);
```

I have a bunch of `setTimeout`s one after another, and what I'm trying to do is update the variables every 3 seconds and run them through the `if` statement again.

Am I even close to doing this properly? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). `setTimeout` only works once.

Comment: You're declaring new local vars inside the function, not accessing the global ones. But doing asynchronous stuff to global state is a confusing debug session waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared those variables with a "var" keyword which makes them local to the function passed to the timeout function. Please remove var and try again.

EDIT : 
As other have pointed out, you should use interval instead of timeout and once the changes are reflected, then only you should try accessing them.

Comment: Yes. Other problems, I think other have answered.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

*JavaScript* has two kind of timers, one provides a timeout (delayed execution of a piece of code) called `window.setTimeout` (because setTimeout is a method of the `window` object) and a timer that runs a piece of code after a certain interval called `window.setInterval`.

Watch how both work

```js
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("showcase").innerHTML += "setTimeout fired only once after 3 seconds. <br />"}, 3000);

setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("showcase").innerHTML += "setInterval fired every after 5 seconds. <br />"}, 5000);


//not part of the solution, just to demonstrate.
setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById("timer").textContent = 1 + parseInt(document.getElementById("timer").textContent);
}, 1000)
```

```css
#showcase {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<span id="timer">0</span> seconds <br />
<div id="showcase"></div>
```

To let a timer run multiple times use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

---

On your case

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var lat_in=5;
    var long_in=5;
    var alt_in=-5;
}, 3000);
```

When you replace `setTimeout` to `setInterval` it still won't work. As others commented, you are declaring the `lat_in` etc. inside the [`scope`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) of the function. This means that the variables inside that function are only accessibele inside the function bound to the interval. The keyword is `var`. It tells the parser to "bind" the variables to the scope of the function. Leave the `var` and your timer function will overwrite the global variables declared outside the function. The sample below should be fine.

```
setInterval(function(){
    lat_in=5;
    long_in=5;
    alt_in=-5;
}, 3000);
```

Also when you first declared the variables they are declared as an empty object.

```js
var lat_in={};
var long_in={};
var alt_in={};
```

using `{}` is the same as doing `lat_in = new Object()`. However in your function you overwrite them with integers. Maybe this isn't meant to be. Check the documentation on your GPS coding to what input it needs.

---

While we are at it:

you can stop timers too with `window.clearTimeout` and `window.clearInterval`. Each referring to its own function of course.

To do this, you need to store the timer into a variable:

```
timer = window.SetInterval(function(){ ... }, 3000); //always in milliseconds.
clearInterval(timer); // this line will now clear the timer.
```

Also a smart person could remark: "I can let `setTimeout` behave like an interval."

```
window.setTimeout(myTimerFunction, 3000);
function myTimerFunction(){
    //do stuff here
    window.setTimeout(myTimerFunction, 3000);  //call itself again in three seconds.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since setTime out is asynchronous you should not start expressions like `lat_out = lat_in;` before initialising.

And also you are declaring the variables using Var which makes them local.so remove var.

Comment: There are several other problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `setInterval` function to call a function after an interval continuesly

```js
$("#Initiate").click(function() {
 var intervalCall = window.setInterval(myCallback, 3000);
)} 

function myCallback(){
  if (coordinate=="GPS")
 {
   console.log("GPS go");
   lat_out = lat_in;
   long_out = long_in;
   alt_out = alt_in;
   console.log(lat_out, long_out, alt_out)
 }

}
```

For more information about `setInterval`, you can [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)